# How to load xml item one at a time as3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

Flash AS3:

Does anyone know how to load items one at a time instead of loading in loop at a normal process using AS3? I'm having problem with overwritten value.

I couldn't make that work, it's always overwritten the last value.I tried to use the dictionary and though it will help to resolve my problem...

I want to be able for EACH button when I clicked it displays the visibility of my markers.

```
private function handleMarkers(event:CustomEventCenter):void
    {
        // Get items info from custom dispatcher
        var nom     = event._name.nom;
        ...

        var tabMarkerID:Array   = new Array();

        // Defined positions for button
        var xPos = 20;
        var yPos = 0;

        // Store the right markerID into each index separated
        if (event._name.markerID == '01') {
            tabMarkerID[0] = event._name.markerID;
        } else if (event._name.markerID == '05') {
            tabMarkerID[1] = event._name.markerID;
        }

        // Create a dictionary  
        var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary(); 

        // Create arrondissement objects for 14 available markers
        var arrond1:Object = new Object();
        var arrond2:Object = new Object();

        dict[arrond1] = tabMarkerID[0];
        dict[arrond2] = tabMarkerID[1];

        for (var i=0;i<2;i++) 
        {
            pointRepere = new PointRepere();
            for (var item:Object in dict)
            {
                if (dict[item] != undefined) {          
                    pointRepere.name = String(dict[item]); // here the issue
                    pointRepere.x = xPos;
                    pointRepere.y = yPos;
                    yPos += i*20 + 40;
                    pointRepere.buttonMode = true;

                    addChild(pointRepere);
                    createMarkers(dict[item], nom);
                    pointRepere.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handlePointClicked);
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private function handlePointClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("Name: "+event.target.name);

        displayMarkerType(event.target.name);
    }


    private function displayMarkerType(id:String):void
    {
        for (var i=0; i< _marker.tabArrondMarker[id].markers.length; i++)
        {
            var marker:Marker = _marker.tabArrondMarker[id].markers[i];
            (!marker.visible) ? marker.visible = true : marker.visible = false; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you have a datagrid. you can put it directly to a dataprovider.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you'd want to lazy load your xml files - you'd need to construct a loop that runs based on an array of the items you want to load - here is an example of how you could do that:

```
private var Array:list;
private var int:count = 0;

private function init()void
{
     list = {"one.xml","two.xml","three.xml"};
     loadXML();
}

private function loadXML():void
{
     //create and init your loader
     var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(list[count]));
     loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
     loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
     loader.load();
}

private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
{
     //Logic here to handle the loaded xml
     continueLoad();
}

private function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
     //Logic here to handle the error
    continueLoad();
}

private function continueLoad():void
{
     if(count < list.length){
          count++;
          loadXML();
     }else{
          //Some logic here to do something else after all of your files have been loaded
     }
}
```

I just this threw this together here so you may need to fix a thing or two but you see the gist - it's a loop that executes only after each individual file has been loaded as opposed to just throwing it all in a for loop and having it execute and subsequently grind and then crash.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unlike your example which is really good tip. Mine is only loaded ONE XML file instead and I need to find a way not to overwritten any value loaded in xml attributes and name.

Let's say xml file structure:
<map>
 <point id="01">
  <name>testing 1</name>
  ...
 </point>
 <point id="02">
  <name>Test2</name>
  ...
 </point>
 ...
</map>

Answer (score 0):

You can load them all, and then reference them by their index. Like

```
xmlData.YourChildNodeName[0]
```

Where the 0 is the index number. This will just pull back the first child node by that name.

Comment: Then can I load to next one?
One item dynamicly at time 

I believe I need a counter